# How do I override the user's input when updating a custom post type's permalink?

Tags: hooks, actions, permalinks

When publishing a custom post type, I'm trying to override the custom permalink based on code rather than what the user types into the input box. I can confirm my action is firing correctly, but I'm suspecting it's being triggered before the update event, so the user's value then overrides mine.

```
add_action('publish_course-variation', 'update_course_variation_permalink', 10, 3);

function update_course_variation_permalink($course_variation_id){

  $cv_meta = get_post_meta($course_variation_id);
  $desired_permalink_value = "my/custom/permalink";

  if( isset($cv_meta['custom_permalink']) ){
      //HAS PERMALINK = CHECK AND UPDATE IF REQUIRED
      if( get_post_meta($course_variation_id, 'custom_permalink', true) != $desired_permalink_value ){
        update_post_meta($course_variation_id, 'custom_permalink', $desired_permalink_value); 
        $results = "UPDATED";
      }else{
        $results = "UNTOUCHED/ALREADY SET CORRECTLY";
      }
  }else{
    //DOESNT HAVE PERMALINK = ADD
    add_post_meta($course_variation_id, 'custom_permalink', $desired_permalink_value, true); 
    $results = "NEW CUSTOM PERMALINK CREATED";
  }



}//end function
```

How do I make my action happen after the post is updated? Or disable the permalink from being updated by hitting 'publish'?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `publish_{post-type}` action is triggered only when the post change from any post status (not published) to published; for example, if the post is already published and you edit it, the `publish_{post-type}` action is not triggered. I think you need to hook your function to `save_post_{post_type}` action, which is triggered every time a post is saved, not matter the status:

```
add_action('save_post_course-variation', 'update_course_variation_permalink', 10, 3);

function update_course_variation_permalink($course_variation_id){

  $cv_meta = get_post_meta($course_variation_id);
  $desired_permalink_value = "my/custom/permalink";

  if( isset($cv_meta['custom_permalink']) ){
      //HAS PERMALINK = CHECK AND UPDATE IF REQUIRED
      if( get_post_meta($course_variation_id, 'custom_permalink', true) != $desired_permalink_value ){
        update_post_meta($course_variation_id, 'custom_permalink', $desired_permalink_value); 
        $results = "UPDATED";
      }else{
        $results = "UNTOUCHED/ALREADY SET CORRECTLY";
      }
  }else{
    //DOESNT HAVE PERMALINK = ADD
    add_post_meta($course_variation_id, 'custom_permalink', $desired_permalink_value, true); 
    $results = "NEW CUSTOM PERMALINK CREATED";
  }

}//end function
```

**Note**: storing data in `custom_permalink` meta field doens't affect to the permalink. Not sure how you are handling the post permalink. I just answered your question about how to trigger the function when a post is updated. If you want to truly override permalink (not a meta field), you could use this (based on this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/128831/37428)):

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'wpse_wp_insert_post_data', 10, 2);
function wpse_wp_insert_post_data($data, $post_attr) {

    $desired_permalink_value = "my/custom/permalink";

    if( ( isset( $data['post_name'] ) && $data['post_name'] != $desired_permalink_value ) || empty( $data['post_name'] ) ) {
        $data['post_name'] = $desired_permalink_value;
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm still having the same problem. I'm able to trace that the hook is being triggered and the permalink meta data is being altered, however it gets overwritten by the value which is entered on the edit page.

Comment: btw, 'custom_permalink' is the the meta key which is used to override the permalink with a plugin called 'custom permalink'.

Comment: How could I know that you are using a plugin??? Anyway, how a plugin works or specific plugin issue is [off-topic here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Your problem overriden the `custom_permalink` meta field was addressed and answered; how it affect to the plugin should be asked to the plugin developer.

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score -3):

You could just do a `display:none` on the css selector for the slug so they never see it.